# LibGDX - How to smooth out actor drawable when scaling a Scene2d stage?

Tags: drawable, libgdx, scaling, smoothing

This is my set-up:

```
stage = new Stage(1280, 800, false);
button = new Button(drawableUp, drawableDown);
stage.add(button);
```

this gets rendered as following:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(RED,GREEN,BLUE,ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);

    stage.draw();
}
```

The issue is that when the stage is shown on 1280x800 the button looks like that:

[image: unscaled image]

If the stage is rescaled to e.g. 1280x736, the button drawable is scaled in the following way:
[image: scaled image]

Is there a way to smooth out the edges somehow? Because right now it looks to me that the scaling is simply done by removing one pixel line in the upper half and one in the lower half of the picture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using filters anywhere in your code? If not, then try this:

```
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Where `texture` is the texture object that you're using.

Comment: Thanks. You have pointed me in the right direction. I have used:
tex = new Texture();
tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, TextureFilter.Linear);