# Libgdx very bad quality of scaled down stage

Tags: libgdx, viewport, scaling, stage

I am doing my very first libgdx game, and I have a problem with the scaling quality.
I created a new class that implements the `Screen` interface.

I programmed everything on that screen as if it was always to run on a 1080x1920 resolution, and then I used the `FitViewport` which I added to the `Stage`.

It works, but the scaling quality is very bad. I understand that it may happen if a graphic is being scaled up to a larger resolution, but the quality is also horrible on lower resolutions.

E.g. here is my `ImageButton` drawn by a `Stage` on a 1080x1920 device:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2STXy.png

And here is how it looks on about 800x480:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/058qo.png

As you can see, the quality is just bad. Since it's scaled down, I would expect it to be much smoother.

I googled a bit and found this post:
[LibGDX - How to smooth out actor drawable when scaling a Scene2d stage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807063/libgdx-how-to-smooth-out-actor-drawable-when-scaling-a-scene2d-stage).

It is recommending to use `setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);` method on a Texture I want to smooth out, but the problem is that I don't have any textures.
I only have a `FitViewport`, `Stage`, `Skin` (loading atlas file), and `ImageButton` actors.

How can I make the scaling quality better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter type is saved in the .atlas file. You can open the file and change the line "filter: Nearest,Nearest" to "filter: Linear,Linear".